# setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false) is not working in fragment

Tags: android, menuitem

I want to hide HomeAsUp in home fragment, i have used this **((MainActivity)getActivity()).hideHome();** but it's not working. I don't want to use SherlockFragmentActivity.

Is this possible to hide HomeAsUp icon without SherlockActivity? If possible then how to use it.

When i inflate the Home fragment the code as like below

```
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.homemenu:
                    // mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    //                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false); // show back button
                    fragmentClass = Home.class;
                    try {
                        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
                    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_anim, R.anim.exit_anim, R.anim.pop_enter, R.anim.pop_exit).replace(R.id.activity_main_content_fragment, fragment).commit();
                    return true;
}
```

Comment: when you inflate home fragment, just replace fragment and commit,. remove addtobackstact() from code.

Comment: why you are not using toolbar?

Comment: I have updated code while i'm inflate the Home fragment!!!

Comment: are u using other fragments that replace home fragment? and want to show back aero in other fragments, and in home just show hamburger menu?

Answer (score 2):

Try Below solution:

**1** - If your activity is AppCompatActivity:

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```

**or** - If your activity is FragmentActivity:

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
getActivity().getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```

Comment: means u wanna to code in fragment that hide Menu, right?

Comment: Is your `SherlockActivity` an AppCompatActivity or FragmentActivity?

Comment: yeah i want to code in fragment that hide the menu and i'm using AppCompatActivity!

Comment: i have took Home extend Fragment!

Comment: If you find this answer helpful, upvote as upperArrow clicked besides answer.

Comment: Then you should provide code or I can help you by 'AnyDesk' computer remote application.

Comment: Sorry. If you scare. I mean that attach your `SherlokActivity` and `HomeFragment` code here in your question and make sure dont add(or hide) packageName or any secure things in your code. So, any one can help you.